# Select child element of previous element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I go about selecting a child element of a previous element. I know how to select the previous element using .prev(), but how do I selected the child element of that previous element so that I can modify the CSS? Thanks for any help.

jQuery:

```
$("li.selected").prev().css("border-right", "none");
```

EDIT:

I would like only the element before the element with the "selected" class to have css style applied to it. Currently all elements are having the css selector applied. Thanks.

```
<ul id="nav_1510737">
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="/bookkeeping">Bookkeeping</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ms-office-support">MS Office Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="/office-organization">Office Organization</a></li>
    <li><a href="/virtual-services">Virtual Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/grant-writing">Grant Writing</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code seem to work perfectly: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agrimsrud/5N4ME/). Maybe interference with your CSS?

Comment: @AndersG Yea, I used JSFiddle and it worked correctly there, just not on the live site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)**:

```
$("li.selected").prev().children().css("border-right", "none");
```

Please note that `.children()` only go down one level from the parent node, if you want to traverse multiple levels then you can use **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**:

```
$("li.selected").prev().find('*').css("border-right", "none");
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way to only do it on the one before it and not all of them?

Comment: I don't get what you means. Can you show a sample HTML markup and state what's your expected result?

Comment: Then your code with only `.prev()` should work. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pLLEC/

Comment: Hm, then I have no idea why it isn't working correctly. It works right for me when I updated the fiddle with what I was trying to do.

Comment: Did you wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(function() {...});` ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to find the previous child of active `<li>` tag.

```
 $("li.selected").prev().find('a').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Hope this help.